# Codecademy React.js dúvida

Tags: javascript, react

Estou a fazer os exercícios de React.js do codecademy.com e fiquei preso nesta questão. Não sei o que tenho mal e não consigo avançar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, fiquei curioso e fui procurar esse exercicio no code academy.

A verdade é: o teu código está certo e é uma maneira válida de resolver o problema, mas o code academy está à espera de algo mais básico, menos correto.

O que o site espera/aceita é:

```
var printS;
if (fiftyFifty) {
  printS = <h1>Tonight I'm going out WOOO</h1>
} else {
  printS = <h1>Tonight I'm going to bed WOOO</h1>
}

return printS;
```

Ou seja, em vez de procurar o pedaço da string que muda com a condição e interpolar como eles têm no exemplo `TodayPlan.js`na linha `return <h1>Today I am going to {task}!</h1>;`, o exercicio vai à procura de código no formato que coloquei em cima.

Lembra-te que o Code Academy é um site onde um robô analisa o código inserido. E se ninguém escrever todas as variantes possíveis, muitas delas ficam de fora e dão resultado negativo no teste.

Resumindo: a tua maneira é correta e muito melhor do que a maneira que o site aceita como correta.

O código que funcionou para mim:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var fiftyFifty = Math.random() < 0.5;

// React.createClass call begins here:
var TonightsPlan = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var printS;
    if (fiftyFifty) {
      printS = <h1>Tonight I'm going out WOOO</h1>
    } else {
      printS = <h1>Tonight I'm going to bed WOOO</h1>
    }

    return printS;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <TonightsPlan />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```